# Herencia en Doctrine

Tags: doctrine

Tengo las siguientes clases

```
class A
{
}

class B extends A
{
}
```

El problema que me surge es que en las tablas la id que las une es diferente al nombre "id", por lo que puedo ver en doctrine toma por defecto ese nombre para vincular las tablas, el caso es que en la tabla A la llave primaria efectivamente se llama id y en la tabla B el primary key es la misma llave foránea que une a las dos tablas, pero tiene un nombre distino id_a, por poner un ejemplo.

El error que me arroja es este:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'on clause'

Este mismo procedimiento lo ocupo en un servicio hecho con Hibernate en java, pero ahí existe una anotación (`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`) con la cual le puedes indicar cómo se llama la llave que une a las tablas, mi pregunta es: ¿en Doctrine existe algo así? ¿O qué podría hacer para resolver este problema?... Sé que quizás lo más fácil sería cambiar el nombre del campo id en la tabla B, pero el caso es que no puedo afectar dicha estructura de la base.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a este artículo https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance creo que tu caso se acerca mucho a la parte de herencia por tablas.

Comment: Gracias, si efectivamente se que tiene que ver con herencia por tablas, lo que no logro averiguar es como indicarle a doctrine que mi llave foranea actua como llave primaria. :(